# Is there any atomic wrapper for objects in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I want to know how to wrap up any instance with getters/setters to atomic wrapper to make that instance thread safe?

```
private Console console;

...

@Override
public Callable<Boolean> execute() {
    return new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {

            console.print("Hi!");

            // some logic

            console.print("Bye!");

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

I need to make `Console` thread safe.

Comment: `synchronized(myObject){ //code}` ?

Comment: Making a class thread-safe is not as simple as wrapping it with some kind of wrapper. It highly depends on what operations exactly you want to make thread-safe.

Comment: by adding wrapper on atomic class, you want to achieve thread safety?

Comment: @praki This is  impossible. I use 3rd party library.

Comment: though that is a 3rd party library, you are creating object for that class right? can you post your code to have clear understanding of what you are looking for?

Comment: @praki I added code snippet.

Comment: Maybe some asm/cglib magic could add synchronization, but that would be tough. Some aspects are to be handle carefully (reentrency).

Comment: Why is @praki suggestion impossible? I mean : `synchronized(console) { console.print("Hi!") }`

Comment: @superbob See my code update.

Comment: Based on your updated code example you want to either change the Console.print method to be synchronized, or if you didn't write that class you should still do synchronized(console){ console.print("Hi"); console.print("Bye"); } as others have suggested.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I need to make `Console` thread safe". What do you want exactly? Canonically, thread-safety means that _it is safe to make it used by many thread concurrently_. The problem is that it depends completely on what the object does internally. Maybe you should tell why it is not actually thread safe and why what we have already suggested doesn't work for you

Answer (score 6):

There is no magic "thread-safety" bullet.  Merely making all getters and setters use atomics does *not* make your class thread-safe.  Even synchronizing all the methods doesn't make the class thread-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Others have pointed out that making updates atomic is not, in and of itself, enough to guarantee thread safety. But to answer your specific question, yes, there is the java.util.concurrent.atomic package for atomic updates in java which you can read about here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html